# How to run emulator in real device?

Tags: android-studio

I get an error in running the emulator.
Take a look at my Screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Emulators don't run on phones, Emulators allow you not to need a phone. However if you want to run your applications on the phone I would suggest starting here http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the device in the list at the top.

It says `UNAUTHORIZED` which means you should go on the phone and allow debugging from this PC (you should be prompted when you plug in the USB).

If that doesn't work try checking if `USB-debugging` is enabled and as a last resort `allow debugging from any PC` *(not recommended)* in the development settings

Answer (score 0):

As you can see you have to set the emulators minSDK to 19 to run your app...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.stackoverflow.answer"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: Mr David, how to set the emulators minSDK and how to write the code that you have given?

Answer (score 0):

[Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l20Ao.png)

I got the answer.I change the min sdk from 21 to 19 at  'app/build.gradle file'

```
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
```